# Can I use Feathers for a real-time site that uses data updated from external sources?

Tags: feathersjs

In [the docs](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/services.html#service-events) it states that Services only emit events when a Service method modifies data. This is the case in all examples I have seen, where a client modifies that data from the browser itself and it gets automatically updated in other clients (like a chat webapp). But what if my data is modified externally outside of Feathers? Will I be able to use Feathers so that the data is updated in all clients?

In my specific case my data is actually stored in a MongoDB database which gets updated externally and autonomously. I want my web application to use MongoDB Change Streams to listen to changes on the MongoDB database (I already know how to do this) and then I want Feathers to take care of sending updates to all my clients in real-time.

In the example chat app, this would be equivalent to having a bot that also writes messages directly to the database outside of Feathers, and this messages should also be broadcasted to clients in real-time.

Is my use-case a good fit for Feathers? Any hint on how should I approach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watching changefeeds has been done for `feathers-rethinkdb` [here](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-rethinkdb/blob/master/lib/index.js#L260). Something similar could be done for MongoDB but there are several challenges discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-rethinkdb/issues/76).

If your MongoDB collection only gets updated externally you could also create a simple pass through service like this:

```
app.use('/feed/messages', {
  async create(data) {
    return data;
  },

  async remove(id) {
    return { id };
  },

  async update(id, data) {
    return data;
  },

  async patch(id, data) {
    return data;
  }
});
```

Which is then called by the changefeed watcher and will automatically take care of updating all the clients through its events.